# C# Application error in others computers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When I run my application in computer which I've developed, it works. Buw I'm getting the following error when I run the app in other computer.

> ******* *Exception Text* ********* System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'itextsharp, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. O sistema
>   não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. File name: 'itextsharp,
>   Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'
>   at LoadImagesFromFolder.cc2215415.button3_Click_1(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> ******* *Loaded Assemblies* ********* mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>
> LoadImagesFromFolder
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/LoadImagesFromFolder.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1002 built by: RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>
> ******* *JIT Debugging* ********* To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory : `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp`

Comment: I know...but how I do for the itextsharp load?

Comment: The error says it all. You obviously use ITextSharp...is it included in your application package or are you expecting users to get it themselves? Either download it and place it in the appropriate place (probably the same location as your app) or bundle it as part of your package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to copy itextsharp.dll also to the new computer

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:The exception that is thrown when an attempt to access a file that does not exist on disk fails.

If your code does not have PathDiscovery permission, the error message for this exception may only contain file or directory names instead of fully qualified paths.

there are some thing missed in target OS.Most likely it fails to load another dependency.check `itextsharp.dll` exist on target OS(near application EXE file)

In your reference Set Copy to local to true to `itextsharp.dll`.its automatically copy `itextsharp.dll` to output near exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iTextSharp assembly is missing. Check your reference settings in visual studio und set Copy local to true if iTextSharp is in the global assembly cache. After this the bin folder also contains the iTextSharp.dll und could be copied to the pc again.